# VS2010 C and C++ - enforce ANSI compliance for Linux/gcc compatibility?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, gcc, visual-c++, standards, ansi-c

I'm taking a class in which I'm required to write some C++ apps for Linux. I really, really dislike the dev tools available under Linux, but I love VS2010.

Is there any sort of compiler switch which will enforce ANSI or gcc compatibility in VC++? Or can I swap the compiler out for gcc and still use the VS environment?

Comment: The VS Project Team blog suggests that with VS2010 it may be possible to use GCC directly with VS - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsproject/archive/2009/06/10/platform-extensibility-part-1.aspx

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can disable Microsoft extensions to the ANSI C and ANSI C++ standards by specifying the  `/Za` flag, which will make the compiler emit errors if you use non-standard C and C++ features.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0k0w269d(v=VS.100).aspx

However, this doesn't preclude you from using platform specific headers.

Comment: Awesome - that's exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but if you want to *disable* Microsoft extensions you *should* specify `/Za`.

Answer (score 3):

This [blog post](http://chrisoldwood.blogspot.com/2009/07/using-visual-c-together-with-gcc-some.html) seems to discuss something similar to what you're after.

I can't seem to find better info than this [MSDN document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sk54f3f5.aspx) regarding VS2010 ANSI compatibility.

Some alternatives to VS2010 include [MonoDevelop](http://monodevelop.com/) - which supports C#, VB.Net, C/C++.

There's also [Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Dev](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-cc-developers/heliossr1).

This [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951516/a-good-c-ide) may also be of use.

Comment: Thanks for the links. I'm not looking for an alternate IDE to use - just a good way to use VS and gcc together. So far I've been testing as I go by recompiling in gcc.