# <iostream> and #define __STDC_WANT_SECURE_LIB__ 0 results in error C2039: 'sprintf_s'

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2019, secure-scl

When building this very simple test program

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    std::cout << "x";
}
```

with visual studio 2019 and `/Wall` I'm getting a

```
warning C4668: '__STDC_WANT_SECURE_LIB__' is not defined as a preprocessor macro, replacing with '0' for '#if/#elif'
```

Trying to

```
#define __STDC_WANT_SECURE_LIB__ 0
```

before including iostream results in

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\include\xlocnum(1388,69): error C2039: 'sprintf_s': is not a member of '`global namespace''
```

at least for my VS. [Godbolt doesn't complain](https://godbolt.org/z/998hhj).

```
#define __STDC_WANT_SECURE_LIB__ 1
```

is fine and doesn't let the compiler complain about sprintf_s which one would expect.

[Microsoft doesn't show me any results when searching for it.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/search/?terms=%22__STDC_WANT_SECURE_LIB__%22). SO does [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19627390/remove-microsoft-specific-extension-of-c) but overall i can't find many resources on if and how to use that define.

Is there a way to disable the secure extensions and include `<iostream>` ? Am i using the wrong define or approach for this?

Comment: You can disable `C4668` for the whole translation unit(s) with [`/wd4668`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/compiler-option-warning-level?view=msvc-160), or just for the std header(s) with `#pragma warning(push)` and [`#pragma warning(disable: 4668)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/warning?view=msvc-160) before `#include <iostream>` then `#pragma warning(pop)` after it. You cannot `#define __STDC_WANT_SECURE_LIB__ 0` because the implementation requires it internally, and that's probably the reason why it's not documented.

Comment: @dxiv what can i do about the C2039 assuming not having the secure extensions is what i want? Or say, how to properly disable the secure extensions?

Comment: Guess you wrote it while I was adding the last sentence to my previous comment. Note that macros starting with a double underscore are reserved for compiler's internal use. You are not supposed to rely on them, let alone redefine them.

Comment: Given it's an internal macro, any idea why it's not defined internally and hits this warning?  Is there some other include required?

Comment: I think this is an error on Microsoft's part. At least for the Windows 10 SDK 10.0.22000.0 that I have, `__STDC_WANT_SECURE_LIB__` is defined in `corecrt.h`. I suppose that somehow, the Microsoft-provided `limits.h` isn't including `corecrt.h` transitively. One way around this, without disabling [`C4668`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-warnings/compiler-warning-level-4-c4668?view=msvc-170) or dropping from `/Wall` to `/W4` is to first include `corecrt.h` but inside a `#ifdef _WIN32 /* ... */ #endif` guard.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, don't have needed permission... blah-blah-blah

'**STDC_WANT_SECURE_LIB**' in VS Community 2022, with pre-compiled CMake SFML-2.6.x
(!)

My mistake was putting the wrong path to folder *"SFML-2.6.x\SFML_cmake_x64\lib\Debug"* - I did not include folder *"\Debug"*. And had the result: *"SFML-2.6.x\SFML_cmake_x64\lib"* -- that's wrong way!!!!!

Every time you must put the full path to folder 'lib' with **\Debug** or **\Release** version